# Display time in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I want to display time store in DB but when i display it show my wrong time with -5 hour less with actual. Suppose i have

```
        $time = '2013-03-18 11:48:26'; 
        $time = date('g:i A M dS', strtotime($time));
        echo $time;
```

then it display  **6:48 AM Mar 18th** it should display **11:48 AM Mar 18th**
can someone tell me what is wrong.
thanks.

Comment: is there a way to set autodetect server timezone

Comment: `CI` is not related to this question. Use only those tags that are related to your question. :)

Comment: Yes: [`date_default_timezone_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php). [Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/l8XVxf).

Comment: sory....actually i was working in ci so i post this tag also

Comment: since your using Codeigniter you can make use of date helper  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html

Comment: @PLB i use **date_default_timezone_get** bt it display **UTC** not time

Comment: @user2166307 `date_default_timezone_get` returns what is default timezone on server. If it's not what you need, change it using `php.ini` or set it from your script.

Answer (score 1):

check your server time zone setting.

or change using php

```
// example for japan time zone

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
```

Comment: I dont want to set any specific timezone i want it jsut get automatic servr timezone

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display time from you database you can use this query.

```
SELECT NOW();
```

And it will give you server time. you can create a helper which can query from model for time and you can call the helper anywhere.